# Clicking Submit button doesn't respond to selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have a form that I fill with some data and everything is OK till I tried to click on Submit button. It doesn't respond at all
Here's the outHTML of the element

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary commandButton" value="إرسال  الطلــب" id="cmdSubmit">
```

I tried these lines

```
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", .FindElementByCss("#cmdSubmit")
```

I even tried byID and byXPATH and nothing worked with the element

While inspecting the webpage, I have searched for submit and I think I found related function

```html
<script>
            $('#frmExecReq').submit(function(){ // catch form submit event
            
                if($('#selectAsed').val() <= 0){
                    $('#selectAsedWarninig').show();
                    return false;
                }
                
                         
                        if(!$.isNumeric($('#phoneNo').val())){
                    $('#phoneNoWarninig').show();
                    return false;
                }
                        
                        
                         var mobileNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNo").value;
                    var mobileLength = mobileNumber.length;
                    var checkFirstNumber = mobileNumber.substring(0, 1);
                    if(mobileNumber ==""){
                                        document.getElementById('phoneNoWarninig').style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById('phoneNo').focus();
                                        document.getElementById('phoneNo').select();
                        return false;
                    }else if( mobileLength !=8 ){
                                        document.getElementById('phoneNoWarninig').style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById('phoneNo').focus();
                                        document.getElementById('phoneNo').select();
                        return false;
                    }else if(checkFirstNumber != 5 && checkFirstNumber != 6 && checkFirstNumber != 9){
                                        document.getElementById('phoneNoWarninig').style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById('phoneNo').focus();
                                        document.getElementById('phoneNo').select();
                        
                        return false;
                    }
                        
                        
                if($('#txtReceivedSum').length){
                    if(!$.isNumeric($('#txtReceivedSum').val())){
                        $('#txtReceivedSumWarninig').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                        //////////
                        
                        var trnCodeNum = document.getElementById("trnCodeNum").value;
                        var persType = document.getElementById("persType").value;
                        if( (trnCodeNum == 0815 && persType == 2) || (trnCodeNum == 0875 && persType == 2) ||  (trnCodeNum == 0820 && persType == 1)
                                || trnCodeNum == 0810 || trnCodeNum == 0825){ 
                                                    
                            var y = document.getElementById('attachments');
                                if ('files' in y) {
                                    if (y.files.length == 0) {
                                        document.getElementById('reqWarning2-1').style.display = 'inline';
                                        //$('#sreqFile1Warning1').show();
                                        return false;
                                    } else {
                                        var file = y.files[0];
                                        if ('name' in file) {
                                            var n = file.name;
                                            fileExtension = n.split('.').pop();

                                            if (!(fileExtension == "pdf")) {
                                                $('#reqWarning2-2').show();
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                            if ('size' in file) {
                                                if (file.size > 10485762) { //10 MB
                                                    $('#reqWarning2-3').show();
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ///////////
                        
                        var form = $('#frmExecReq')[0];
                            // Create an FormData object 
                        var data = new FormData(form)
                
                $.ajax({ // create ajax call
                    data: data, //get form data
                                //contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                method: 'POST',
                    type: $(this).attr('method'), //GET or POST
                    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the action url
                    success: function(response){ // on success
                        $('#viewPaneChildDetails').html(response); //update DIV
                        $('#viewPaneChild').hide();
                        $('#viewPaneChildDetails').show();
                    }
                });
                return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting 
            });
        </script>
```

When trying this line, an error occurred

```
.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='btn btn-primary commandButton' and @id=='dSubmit'][@vlaue='إرسال  الطلــب']").Click
```

[image]

Comment: That's not Python that you're executing...

Comment: I have updated the tags. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  .FindElementByCss("input.btn.btn-primary.commandButton#cmdSubmit").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  .FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='btn btn-primary commandButton' and @id='cmdSubmit']").click
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when trying the line, an error occurred. I have updated the question to insert a picture of the error.

Comment: Removed the _value_ attribute, possibly I was pasting incorrectly. Please retest.

Comment: The same error again. It seems this button is related to javascript function that works in specific way but I didn't experience such a problem before.

Comment: The error must be different now, it shouldn't be _`InvalidSelectorError`_ like before.

Comment: As for the css selector, I got Element Not Found but as for xpath the same error as attached in the picture in the question

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: As for css and xpath the same error `Element not ineractable ElementNotVisibleError`. I noticed when inspecting the element again that `#cmdSubmit` has two results not only one. How can I refer the first instance?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: I tried this line and seems to work `.FindElementsByCss("input.btn.btn-primary.commandButton#cmdSubmit")(2).Click` but how can I implement the second instance in the css selector itself